# Article dans "jour + date"

Tags: articles, dates

Comment faut-il dire:

> On se voit le vendredi 1 septembre.
>
> On se voit le vendredi 14/03 à 9h30.

et/ou

> On se voit vendredi le premier septembre.
>
> On se voit vendredi le 14/03 à 9h30.

, donc avec l'article devant le jour ou devant la date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La date peut s'écrire de façon **verbeuse** :

> Vendredi 23 septembre [2016]
>   Le vendredi 23 septembre [2016]

Dans ce cas, l'utilisation de l'article est *facultative*.

ou de façon **compacte** :

> le 26/09[/2016]

Là, l'article est *obligatoire* pour exprimer une date.

Dans tous les cas, **l'article précède le bloc "jour + date"**

> Le premier septembre
>   Le vendredi premier septembre
>   Le mardi 30 août 2017
>   Le 24/06/1987 à 8h51

**NB** : Si on parle d'une date du mois en cours, on n'est pas obligé de préciser le mois (usage oral ou écrit ponctuel).

> Vendredi 26
>   Le 26